# Displaying JSON data in Chartjs from external JSON File without jQuery

Tags: javascript, json

I'm Trying to Display JSON Data in Chart.js But I Can't Find a way to use the actual_JSON Variable (which is my JSON file as object) in chart, because it's local. can someone help me in this?

```js
//Get JSON Data
function loadJSON(callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://filebin.net/bddbcas2xtfiufnj/data.json?t=at5f150y', true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(null);
}

(function init() {
  loadJSON(function(response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
    consumeData(actual_JSON); //Use this to consume JSON Data 
  });
})()
//*********************************************************************
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: [], //Using JSON Object Here
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
    }]
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does local mean?

Comment: @Wolfetto I mean local variable . See my code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.getJSON():` function including JQuery library in your software

```
$.getJSON('https://filebin.net/bddbcas2xtfiufnj/data.json?t=at5f150y', function(data) {
    //data is the JSON string. Pass data to chart 
});
```

Comment: Yeah thanks but I mentioned that how can I do it without jQuery

Comment: I tried your code. Everything is working except for your JSON (is not valid JSON). Please adjust JSON and check it with JsonValidator (online tool). After that you can pass the value to your chart